# How does the DHCP server know my IP Address?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

[image]

The Destination of packet No.17, 22, 200, 390, 531, 535 should be broadcast message, but why are they my ip address?
Note that I have released my IP.

Comment: "_The Destination of packet No.17, 22, 200, 390, 531, 535 should be broadcast message..._" Why do you think that?

Comment: Well @RonMaupin, the DHCP spec says they should be (or at least, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol does ... I haven't checked the spec.)

Comment: You should read the RFC for DHCP.

Comment: Yea ... I should.  Wikipedia is misleading.

Comment: Thanks... I should learn to check the RFC.

Comment: You get what you pay for on Wikipedia. It is often a good place to start, but it is not the standard itself. Anyone can add to or update Wikipedia, so you may get incorrect or misleading information. The references at the bottom of an article are often very valuable, but you must look at them with a critical eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only specific circumstances where the DHCPOFFER and DHCPACK should be broadcast. In most cases, those should be unicast back to the requesting host.

The server knows the MAC address of the requesting host, so the frame is unicast back to the requesting host unless the requesting host has set the broadcast bit in the DHCPREQUEST.

See [*RFC 2131, Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt):

> Normally, DHCP servers and BOOTP relay agents attempt to deliver
>   DHCPOFFER, DHCPACK and DHCPNAK messages directly to the client using
>   unicast delivery.  The IP destination address (in the IP header) is
>   set to the DHCP 'yiaddr' address and the link-layer destination
>   address is set to the DHCP 'chaddr' address.  Unfortunately, some
>   client implementations are unable to receive such unicast IP datagrams
>   until the implementation has been configured with a valid IP address
>   (leading to a deadlock in which the client's IP address cannot be
>   delivered until the client has been configured with an IP address).
>
> A client that cannot receive unicast IP datagrams until its protocol
>   software has been configured with an IP address SHOULD set the
>   BROADCAST bit in the 'flags' field to 1 in any DHCPDISCOVER or
>   DHCPREQUEST messages that client sends.  The BROADCAST bit will
>   provide a hint to the DHCP server and BOOTP relay agent to broadcast
>   any messages to the client on the client's subnet.  A client that can
>   receive unicast IP datagrams before its protocol software has been
>   configured SHOULD clear the BROADCAST bit to 0.  The BOOTP
>   clarifications document discusses the ramifications of the use of the
>   BROADCAST bit [21].

-and-

> In the case of a client using DHCP for initial configuration (before
>   the client's TCP/IP software has been completely configured), DHCP
>   requires creative use of the client's TCP/IP software and liberal
>   interpretation of RFC 1122.  The TCP/IP software SHOULD accept and
>   forward to the IP layer any IP packets delivered to the client's
>   hardware address before the IP address is configured; DHCP servers and
>   BOOTP relay agents may not be able to deliver DHCP messages to clients
>   that cannot accept hardware unicast datagrams before the TCP/IP
>   software is configured.
>
> To work around some clients that cannot accept IP unicast datagrams
>   before the TCP/IP software is configured as discussed in the previous
>   paragraph, DHCP uses the 'flags' field [21].  The leftmost bit is
>   defined as the BROADCAST (B) flag.  The semantics of this flag are
>   discussed in section 4.1 of this document.  The remaining bits of the
>   flags field are reserved for future use.  They MUST be set to zero by
>   clients and ignored by servers and relay agents.  Figure 2 gives the
>   format of the 'flags' field.
>
> ```
>                                  1 1 1 1 1 1
>              0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
>             +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>             |B|             MBZ             |
>             +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>             B:  BROADCAST flag
>
>             MBZ:  MUST BE ZERO (reserved for future use)
>
>             Figure 2:  Format of the 'flags' field
> ```